# Where Kblocks store the highscore?

Tags: gnome, kde

I would like to make a clean install in my computer, but I play a lot of with Kblocks (KDE Tetris game on GNOME) and If it possible I would like to copy the highscore to the new (Maverick) system too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The high score is stored in the configuration file (which is a questionable design choice if you ask me, but whatever...) at `~/.kde/share/config/kblocksrc`.

Comment: Yeah, questionable indeed. Games usually store high scores inside  `/var/games`, IIRC (or was it `/usr/games`?).

Comment: @badp: Right, exactly.

Comment: No file in /var/games. In usr/games there is the startup file only

Comment: @Robert, have you read the answer proper?

Comment: Yay! You are super! :)